# How to know if a variation (f.e. abbreviation) of a string in a list does match agains another list if the original does not?

Tags: regex, r, merge, pattern-matching, matching

I currently searching for a method in R which let's me match/merge two data frames. Helas both of these data frames contain non optimal data. They can have certain abbreviations of even typo's in them. Therefore I would like to define a list for each abbreviation and if a string contains one of those elements. If the original entries don't match, R should check if any of the other options of the abbreviation has a match. To illustrate: the name of a company could end with "Limited" but also with "Ltd." of "Ltd" etc.

### EXAMPLE

---

### Data

The Original "Address" file contains:

```
Company name         Address 
Deloitte Ltd.        New York
Coca-Cola            New York
Tesla ltd            California
Microsoft Limited    Washington
```

Would have to be merged with "EnterpriseNrList"

```
Company name         EnterpriseNumber
Deloitte Ltd.        221
Coca-Cola            334
Tesla ltd            725
Microsoft Limited    127
```

So the abbreviations should work in "both directions". That's why I said, if R recognises any of the abbreviations, R should try to match all of them. 
All of the matches should be reported as the return.

Therefore I would make up a list "Abbreviations"  for each possible abbreviation

```
Limited.
limited 
Ltd.
ltd. 
Ltd
ltd
```

### Questions

---

1) Would this be a good method, or would there be a more efficient way?

2) How can I check a list against a list of possible abbreviations (step 1, see below), sort of a containsx from excel?

3) How could I make up a list that replaces for the entries that do not match the abbreviation with all other abbreviatinos (step 2, see below)?

### Thoughts for solution

---

### Step 1

As I am still very new to this kind of work, I was thinking the following: use a regex expression to filter out wether a string contains any of the abbreviation options and create a list which will then contain either -1 if no match could be found and >0 if match is found. The no pattern matching can already be matched against the "Address" list. With the other entries I continue to step 2.

In this step I don't really know how to check against a list of options ("Abbreviations" list).

### Step 2

Next I would create a list with the matches from step 1 and rbind together all options. In this step I don't really know to I could create a list that combines f.e. Coca-Cola with all it's possible abbreviations.

```
Coca-Cola Limited
Coca-Cola Ltd. 
Coca-Cola Ltd
etc.
```

### Step 3

Lastly I would match/merge this more complete list of companies again with the original "Data" list. With the introduction of step 2 I thought It might be a bit easier on the required computing power, as the original list is about 8000 rows.

Comment: Thank you for thinking out your question ahead of time and detailing your approach. You can complete your question by showing the desired output for the example. Do you want Microsoft to match with Washington and 127? For Coca-Cola, New York and 334? In that case, eliminate the "ltd" and "limited" parts since you are not expecting "Apple" and "Apple Limited" to be separate companies. Also punctuation should be removed.

Comment: Thank you Pierre for you reply. The example I gave above might indeed be a bit redundant. However, as I am comparing a file against the national database of companies, some of those companies have in there official name an abbreviation. F.e. a co-ownship is sometimes abbreviated as CO, sometimes as C.O. or co-own. etc. I want to check wether my list isn't just one of the others before concluding it isn't in the national database. Removing all abbreviations, as you suggested, might create a duplicate which wasn't one before.

Comment: The way I would go about this is to first try an exact match, then try a partial match on the first word of each entry, which should take care of all Limited/Ltd etc problems, and last a partial match (using eg, agrep()), that should take care of most misspelled words.

Answer (score 1):

I would go in a different approach, fixing the tables first before the merge.

To fix with abreviations, I would use a regex, case insensitive, the final dot being optionnal, I start with a list of 'Normal word' = vector of abbreviations.

```
abbrevs <- list('Limited'=c('Limited','Ltd'),'Incorporated'=c('Incorporated','Inc'))
```

The I build the corresponding regex (alternations with an optional dot at end, the case will be ignored by parameter in gsub and agrep later):

```
regexes <- lapply(abbrevs,function(x) { paste0("(",paste0(x,collapse='|'),")[.]?") })
```

Which gives:

```
$Limited
[1] "(Limited|Ltd)[.]?"

$Incorporated
[1] "(Incorporated|Inc)[.]?"
```

Now we have to apply each regex to the company.name column of each df:

```
for (i in seq_along(regexes)) { 
  Address$Company.name <- gsub(regexes[[i]], names(regexes[i]), Address$Company.name, ignore.case=TRUE)
  Enterprise$Company.name <- gsub(regexes[[i]], names(regexes[i]), Enterprise$Company.name, ignore.case=TRUE)
}
```

This does not take into account typos. Here you'll need to work on with `agrep`or `adist` to manage it.

Result for Address example data set:

```
> Address
       Company.name    Address
1  Deloitte Limited   New York
2         Coca-Cola   New York
3     Tesla Limited California
4 Microsoft Limited Washington
```

Input data used:

```
Address <- structure(list(Company.name = c("Deloitte Ltd.", "Coca-Cola", 
"Tesla ltd", "Microsoft Limited"), Address = c("New York", "New York", 
"California", "Washington")), .Names = c("Company.name", "Address"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Enterprise <- structure(list(Company.name = c("Deloitte Ltd.", "Coca-Cola", 
"Tesla ltd", "Microsoft Limited"), EnterpriseNumber = c(221L, 
334L, 725L, 127L)), .Names = c("Company.name", "EnterpriseNumber"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the answer depends on whether you have a list of abbreviations or not.

If you have one, you could just look which element of your list contains an abbreviation with `grep` or  `grepl`functions. (grep return all indexes that have a matching pattern whereas grepl returns a logical vector).
Also, use the `ignore.case= TRUE` parameter of these function, so you don't have to try all capitalized/lowercase possibilities.

If you don't have such a list, my first guest would be to extract the first "word" of each company (I would guess that there is a single "Deloitte" company, and that it is "Deloitte Ltd"). You can do so with:
`unlist(strsplit(CompanyNames,split = " "))`

If you wanted to also correct for typos, this is more a question of string distance.

Hope that it helped!

Comment: This has the problem of companies with space in their names, like ' Airbus, Airbus Defence and Space, Airbus Helicopters, etc.' which are branches of  'Airbus Group'. They would all end up all under 'Airbus' with this method.

Comment: You're right, I did not think of this. But then it depends on what is the aim afterwards, maybe joining all branches was the next step (and I would be lucky with my answer).
The first part still holds true, but you gave a more extensive version of it!

Comment: I was just a warning for future readers as I did feel it was not visible enough in your answer :)